# createClass within createClass in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react and confused with the concept of component. I know one component can be inclued within another but this time I'm seeing in one createClass there's another createClass.

view-source:http://chrisharrington.github.io/demos/react-controls/calendar.html

in like 116, how does it look like in es6?

Comment: There is no `createClass` inside another class. They are creating **Calendar, DayNames, and Week** independently as components.

Comment: @Hosar can you look at `var DayNames = React.createClass({...})` ? why don't just use a normal function? It's a component, how does that look like in es6?

Answer (score 0):

As an example, here's the component using `React.createClass`.

```
var DayNames = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div className="week names">
      <span className="day">Sun</span>
      <span className="day">Mon</span>
      <span className="day">Tue</span>
      <span className="day">Wed</span>
      <span className="day">Thu</span>
      <span className="day">Fri</span>
      <span className="day">Sat</span>
    </div>;
  }
});
```

Here it is again as a stateless function component.

```
function DayNames() {
  return <div className="week names">
    <span className="day">Sun</span>
    <span className="day">Mon</span>
    <span className="day">Tue</span>
    <span className="day">Wed</span>
    <span className="day">Thu</span>
    <span className="day">Fri</span>
    <span className="day">Sat</span>
  </div>;
}
```

And here it is again as an ES2015 class.

```
class DayNames extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div className="week names">
      <span className="day">Sun</span>
      <span className="day">Mon</span>
      <span className="day">Tue</span>
      <span className="day">Wed</span>
      <span className="day">Thu</span>
      <span className="day">Fri</span>
      <span className="day">Sat</span>
    </div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: declare function component within or outside the class? I need to convert everything to es6.

Comment: A function component is an alternative to a class component. You can use them if your component doesn't use `this.state`.

Answer (score 0):

On ES6 and react 0.14 above, you can also use a stateless functional component , e.g.

```
const DayNames = () => ( 
  <div className="week names"> 
    <span className="day">Sun</span> 
    <span className="day">Mon</span> 
    <span className="day">Tue</span> 
    <span className="day">Wed</span> 
    <span className="day">Thu</span> 
    <span className="day">Fri</span> 
    <span className="day">Sat</span> 
  </div> 
)
```

Comment: what does it means by functional? I don't see any function in this function/component. The `return` is not needed here?

Comment: @Mellisa Its a function instead of ES6 class with out the , the `function` keyword here is replaced by `()`, then `return` is not needed because it is enclosed by an expressions `(...)`

Comment: why there's no render function here?